# TypeScript video tutorials

Tags: typescript

Apologies if I am posting this question at wrong place.

Is there any good video learning resources available for TypeScript language from Microsoft. Any link or help will be  greatly appreciated.

Comment: Recommendations for tutorials are off topic; try to ask questions that are *specific* and about *real code*.

Comment: Which is the best place to seek recommendations for tutorials?

Comment: Amit Mittal, `Which is the best place to seek recommendations for tutorials?` **GOTO comment 1**

Comment: I've started making a few : http://www.youtube.com/basaratali

Comment: Though it is off topic but I will upvote it. Off topic doesn't mean it won't help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not free but  [PluralSight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/typescript) has some excellent videos.